# In Minecraft how do you save yourself if you fall in Lava?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When mining Glowstone or finding rare areas of Nether Wart, if I fall into the lava how do I save myself from dying?

Comment: thats how to save inventory, not self

Comment: @JLaBella If you'll look at the accepted answer, it details how to save yourself.

Comment: @SaintWacko Separate questions can have the same answer, but they are not the same question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One option is to use [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-now-open-source/) to load up the world you were playing in and move your character out of the lava and into water. This will put the fire out and allow you to survive.

Another option is, if you have cheats turned on, to quickly type `/gamemode <yourname> 1` in order to change yourself to creative mode and thus prevent yourself from taking damage.

Comment: on setting gamemode, you can just type /gamemode 1 or /gamemode c (no username defaults to self)

Comment: Ah, that's good to know. Last time I used the command to change gamemode, that wasn't available.

Comment: -1 how is "use a cheat" considered an answer? O_o _(unless, of course, the OP asked specifically for a cheat)_

Comment: @Lohoris Look at it another way: The OP didn't say he *didn't* want a cheat, and it answers the question "In Minecraft how do you save yourself if you fall in Lava?", so how is it *not* considered an answer?

Comment: Seriously? I… don't know what to say, this is so wrong I don't know where to start. It's so obvious that "use a cheat" is not an answer that… I don't know.

Comment: @Lohoris Considering that this is the accepted answer, the OP seems to have disagreed with you.

Comment: @SaintWacko I've seen many wrong answer accepted, so the OP disagreeing with me isn't really relevant. "In general" this sort of answer isn't valid. The fact that worked here is an accident.